# Is using the \bf command for bolding text OK?

Tags: bold

I see many questions where the macro `\bf` is used to generate a bold output. Is this a good use of `\bf`?

Comment: this is a duplicate of the question just asked or at least  the accepted answer at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/636367/1090  applies equally to text and math mode use.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I think Peter just wanted to create something that could be referred to whenever people ask about `\bf`, which is why he also answered immediately

Comment: Define "good.".

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Please see the edited version of my answer.

Comment: Related: [Will two-letter font style commands (`\bf` , `\it` , …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15361/5764)

Comment: @PeterWilson well your answer isn't wrong but  I don't think it says anything different to the text of the answer posted yesterday, as I say while the question yesterday asked about math use he answer (that it may not be defined) applied equally to text or math

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I know I'm a GOM and please make allowances for that. Putting myself as a new LaTeX user i did not see anything in your answer that dealt with other the `\bf` in math mode. Please extend your answer to tell folk what to do if they come across `\bf` in other than math mode (as I tried to do in my answer)..

Comment: @PeterWilson apart from literally the last word, `\mathbf`, the whole answer applied equally to text and math but I added `or `\textbf{set}`in text.` to make it clearer for you.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you. As a long time LaTeX user I understood that your answer had general applicability. What I was concerned about was newcomers who might not realise that there were text equivalents of `\mathbf`. I'm very happy with your current answer.

Answer (score 5):

No, it is not a good use and should not be used at all in any modern LaTeX (post 1993) document.

BEGIN EDIT re comments

Other questions have been asked about this, for example about using `\bf` when typesetting maths, and with specific answers. This is an attempt to provide a generic answer not dependant on the particular desired typography.

END EDIT

`\bf` has not been defined in LaTeX2e since 1993, although it is still defined if you use TeX, not LaTeX.

Instead use:

`I say \textbf{boldly go} onwards` or `I say {\bfseries boldly go} onwards`. In math use `\mathbf{boldly go}`

Some classes or packages may define `\bf` or suggest using something else. For example the `book`, `report` and `article` classes define their version of `\bf` for compatibilty reasons with pre-1993 created documents.

The `memoir` class, and maybe many others, does not recognise `\bf` and will give warnings if it is used (although there is a class option that lets you use it).

Essentially, do not employ `\bf`. And package writers should certainly avoid it.